# Get card token from Stripe on android

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I'm using the set of instructions from https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android/standard in my Android/Kotlin app, and on the final `onPaymentSessionDataChanged()` callback, I get a `PaymentMethod` with an id that starts with `pm_`. But what I want is a card token id that starts with `card_`, which is what my server requires to continue payment.

Is there a way to translate this to get the card token, or should I be using a different methodology?

If it helps, I can put some code here.

Thanks.

Comment: PaymentMethods are for use with the PaymentIntents API: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/android. Depending on your flow you might want to change your methodology to create a Source instead of a PaymentMethod.

Comment: Thanks for that, @PaulAsjes. I'll give that a try.

Comment: @PaulAsjes, if i did stick to the `Payment method` as suggested by the stripe site, is it possible to pass the `pm_` code to my server to complete the payment, or would i still need to get the card details from the user and use the `Payments Intent` api for that?

Comment: You could pass the PaymentMethod to your server and it use to create a PaymentIntent there (https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create?lang=node#create_payment_intent-payment_method) however if the payment requires 3DS then you'd need to handle that on your frontend.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
Token token = null;

final Card card = new Card(cardNumber, month, year, cvc);

final Stripe stripe = new Stripe(getApplicationContext());
try {

    token = stripe.createTokenSynchronous(card, "YOUR-API-KEY");

} catch (StripeException stripeEx) {

    errorMessage = stripeEx.getLocalizedMessage();
}
```

Comment: How to add Cardholder name? to the card object.

Comment: @Shivam You will need to create a Map and put "name" : "Matteo" in it. You can follow the example here : https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/create